# How can I get the same plot without the intermediate step of the amount aggregation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

How can I get the same plot without the intermediate compute of the aggregate column.

I have this data :

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(month = gl(3,1,20),
                  family= gl(5,1,20),
                  amount= sample(1:3,20,rep=TRUE))
```

Using this code , I get a barplot  . Where each bar , is the sum of amount by family and by month. first I create a new aggegate column V1.

```
## I am using data.table , you can get it by ddply also
library(data.table)
dd <- data.table(dat)
hh <- dd[,sum(amount),by=list(month,family)]
```

Then I plot using this code :

```
ggplot(data=hh,aes(x=month,y=V1,fill=family))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

To get this plot:

[image]

This works but I want simpler method. I think using `stat_sum` or other `ggplot2` techniques I can do this without the intermediate aggregation step. something like this :

```
 ## don't run this doesn't work
 ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=month,y=amount,fill=family))+
  geom_bar(stat = "sum")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=month,y=amount,fill=family,group=family))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary",fun.y=sum)
```

[image]

Comment: ! pretty and simple thanks! maybe you can add some explanation ... looks like you don't need the group aes ...

Comment: You need the group to get the ordering correct. I'm not sure why and I'm not able to find out what ggplot2 does under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

I found on  [R help mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ggplot2-stacked-bar-sum-of-values-rather-than-count-td4298342.html) that there is a an argument `weight=` than can be used to get sum of particular values instead of count in producing stacked bar charts. You have to supply `x` values, `fill=` values and `weight=amount` ensures that sum of `amount` values is used to make bar heights. This also automatically ensures that `fill=` values are arranged in the same order.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(month,fill=family,weight=amount))+geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 good answer! I check the other answer since it seems more general ( can get mean or median)...